# Get maximum value of an aggregate function

Tags: postgresql

I want to only return the row where the `count(object)` is the highest, so I have written this query

```
select klantnr, count(objectnaam)
from klanten inner join deelnames using(klantnr)
inner join reizen using(reisnr)
inner join bezoeken using(reisnr)

where objectnaam = 'Maan'

group by klantnr
```

Now, I can't do

```
select max(count(objectnaam))
```

How would I go about solving this problem?

I have tried by using a subquery which is equally invalid

```
select max(select count(objectnaam) from ....)
```

I think I need a subquery in the from, so I have rewritten the query like this which I think is closer to the actual answer but still not right, as now it returns the maximum value of all rows.

```
       select klantnr, max(c)
FROM(
select klantnr, count(objectnaam) as c
from klanten inner join deelnames using(klantnr)
inner join reizen using(reisnr)
inner join bezoeken using(reisnr)
where objectnaam = 'Maan'
group by klantnr) as F

group by klantnr
```

thanks for any help you can give me!

Answer (score 0):

You do not provide the structure of tables, so probably you have to modify the following query. However it works just for PostgreSQL 9.x+

```
WITH t AS (
  SELECT klantnr, COUNT(objectnaam) AS c 
  FROM klanten 
  WHERE objectnaam = 'Maan'
  GROUP BY klantnr
  ORDER BY c DESC
  LIMIT 1
)
SELECT * FROM t
INNER JOIN deelnames USING(klantnr)
INNER JOIN reizen USING(reisnr)
INNER JOIN bezoeken USING(reisnr);
```

see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-with.html how to use WITH QUERIES.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a simpeler solution:

```
select  klantnr,count (klantnr)
from  bezoeken natural join deelnames
where objectnaam ='Maan'
group by klantnr
order by count desc
limit 1
```